# Anchor tag not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, anchor, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm building a small project and I've got a lot of answers here already, so thank you in advance.

My problem now is getting the anchor tags to work on mobile devices.
The anchor tags seems to work fine on desktop devices but when I try to click them on an iPhone I get no results.

---

EDIT: Explaining better (thank you Andrei Gheorghiu for the advice): 
If I open the codepen on a device like my desktop computer, the navbar works as expected: it collapses as it reaches the @media queries breakpoints, and upon collapsing with width < 768, the collapsed navbar shows the toggler icon and all the anchor tags are clickable and working (they redirect me to the div as the JavaScript should).
When I load the page on my iPhone 7, however, the navbar is collapsed as expected, but clicking on the anchor tags doesn't get me anywhere.

I tried Andrei Gheorghiu's both suggestions but they didn't solve the problem, at least on my phone (thank you very much, still!). I really think the problem is related to the anchor tag, as removing the javascript dealing with the scrolling and linking the anchor tags hrefs directly with simple IDs didn't work either.

---

Any help?
I'm using bootstrap 4, the codepen is here: https://codepen.io/diegomengue/pen/VWWjpj.

HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body> 
  <nav class='navbar navbar-inverse navbar-toggleable-sm mx-auto sticky-top'>
    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed mx-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class='navbar-nav mx-auto'>
      <li class='nav-item mx-auto'><a href='#' id='inicioMenu' class='nav-link'><strong>Diego Mengue</strong></a></li>
      <li class='nav-item mx-auto'><a href='#' id='portfolioMenu' class='nav-link'>Portfólio</a></li>
      <li class='nav-item mx-auto'><a href='#' id='contatoMenu' class='nav-link'>Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>         
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #EAEDFB;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;


.navbar{
  background-color: #6F7ECC;
  top: 0.5em;
  width: 74%;
}

li {
  padding: 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
  margin: 0 0.3em 0 0.3em;
}

a {
  color: white;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #D9DDF3;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

form {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

p {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.vertical-align {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#icone {
  width:  2.5em;
  margin: 0 0.6em 0 0.6em;
}

hr {
  background-color: white;
}

h1, h2 {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
#divPortfolio {
  height: 800px;
}

.text-right {
  margin-right: 0.3em;
}

footer {
  background-color:#6F7ECC;
  width: 74%;
  text-align: center;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   font-size: 1em!important;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
      font-size: 1em!important;
}
::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
      font-size: 1em!important;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) {
  body {font-size: 10px;}
  .navbar {font-size:1.2em;}
  footer {font-size: 0.6em; height: 5em; padding-top: 1.4em;}
  h4 {margin-top: 1em;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {font-size: 13px;}
  .navbar {font-size: 1.2em;}
  footer {font-size: 1em;  height: 3em;
  padding-top: 1.4em;}
  h4 {margin-top: 0em;}
  }

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  body {font-size: 14px;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  body {font-size: 16px;}
}
```

JS:

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 768px)" );

function scrollToAnchor(aid){
    var aTag = $(aid);
  if (mq.matches) {
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: (aTag.offset().top)-82},'slow');
  } else {
    $('body').animate({scrollTop:(aTag.offset().top)-180},'slow');
  }
};

   $("#inicioMenu").on('click touchend', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  scrollToAnchor("#inicio");
  return false;
});

$("#portfolioMenu").on('click touchend', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  scrollToAnchor('#portfolio');
  return false;
});

$("#contatoMenu").on('click touchend', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
   scrollToAnchor('#contato');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: How do I up this question?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to not have loaded `tether(.min).js`, which is required by Bootstrap 4 and should be loaded before `bootstrap(.min).js`. Always get the latest version from [Bootstrap webpage](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) (under **Easy to get started**). That will, most likely, fix your problem and, if it does, do not take the next steps.

If it doesn't, remember IoS is special. Really special. Long story short, you probably need to map `click` functionality to `touchend` event as well.

Replacing each occurrence of `click()` according to this model...

```js
$("#inicioMenu").on('click touchend', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  scrollToAnchor("#inicio");
  return false;
});
```

... will, most likely, fix it. The most important part is the `preventDefault()`, which fixes `scrollTop` issues on some versions of IoS devices.

Also, make sure you're not setting `pointer-events:none;` to your `<a>` tags (because it would disable them on IoS).

You should note the snippet you provided is not a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (it doesn't reproduce the problem). If the above general advice does not work, you need to update your question with a verifiable example (or with more technical info about the device you're testing on) so the cause could be pinpointed.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried your suggestions but sadly they didn't work out for me (supposing I didn't do something wrong). I updated the code (switched the click() part and added tether.js) and the problem persists.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I'm answering in case someone comes looking for an answer like I did!

For me it was an easy fix: mobile menu links to pages would work but not anchor tags to areas within the same page. The answer was to include the full URL in the a tag, not just the anchor. E.g. www.yoursite.com/#youranchor (instead of) #youranchor.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers worked for me so I used this for navigation

```
onclick="window.location.href = './about.html';
```

Earlier my code was like below

```
 <li>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="./about.html"> About</a>
</li>
```

but the anchor was not working on mobile. then i made it to

```
 <li onclick="window.location.href = './about.html';">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="./about.html"> About</a>
</li>
```

I know this is not the right way but this can be a quick fix for sure.